# How much salt is left in the tank when the water is 50 gal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

A tank contains $200 gal$ brine at the beginning and $15 lb$ salt in it!
$t=0$, brine $4 \frac{lb}{gal}$ flows in with a speed of $3.5\frac{gal}{min}$. The out flow of the tank is $4\frac{gal}{min}$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=14-\frac{4x}{200-.5t}$$

Solving...

$$\frac{x}{(400-t)^8}=2(400-t)^{-7}+c$$

$$c=\frac{-785}{400^8}$$

We want to determine how much salt is left in the tank when it has only 50 gal of water!

My attempt

$200-.5t=50 \iff t=300$

By setting t-300 into the equation to solve for x-the salt left.

Is this the right way to do it? Or something is wrong!

Comment: Barring any algebraic mistakes, your method is correct.

Comment: Just curious. Do I have any algebraic mistakes on the post?

Comment: The general solution seems correct, but I didn't check if you got the right $c$ (:

Comment: Is the flow in $14$ or $4$ ?

Comment: Out flow 4 in flow 3.5. For speed only.

Comment: Ah ok. The differential equation looks right from, too.

Comment: Isn´t $200-0.5t$ just the amount of brine at time t ?

Comment: Yes. But the solution will decrease since the out is more than in with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems fine. Well done!

Comment: The question is literally:  Is this the right way to do it. My answer: yes. Why exactly is this not an answer?